# Rotating a PDF file by n degrees, where n is not a multiple of 90

Tags: pdf

The problem I am facing is as following. I have a source document, src.pdf.

I need to insert the contents of src.pdf into target.pdf, rotated by *n* degrees, where *n* is NOT a multiple of 90.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

PDF contains no annotations.

I can use any solution which relies on utilities, or write my own code, preferably in C#/Python/Ruby/Perl, but not limited to a language.

The platform is Windows Server 2008 R2, I prefer to stick to the existing server but Linux is also an option. Latest (stable) GhostScript and pdftk are already installed.

Comment: Do you need utility programs or are you also ready to do some coding given some helper libraries? Which platform? And does your source PDF also contain annotations, not only static page content?

Comment: Hi @mkl, I've edited the question and added these details in response, thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If a new language is not a problem, LateX could be an option. You can include a pdf as a figure in a tex file, and you will be able to use dedicated option like rescaling and rotating function. Then, compile it to obtain a new pdf.
The very simple following code works for me :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5,angle=10]{test.pdf} 

\end{document}
```

From this pdf:

[image: str]

I get this new one:

[image]

It will however need some manual ajustements to get exactly what you want...

Comment: @yms indeed, reminds me of university days... ;) Unless Roman already uses TeX on his system, though, that looks like quite a big install given the task.

Comment: I decided to go with PDFLaTeX, as it provides all the required shift, cut, convert and rotate operations in a single, free tool. Thank you very much for the tip!

Comment: @Roman Hey, I have PDFLaTex - how did you rotate your existing pdf document?

Comment: How can I rotate every page of a multi-page pdf this way?  Using this method only gets you the first page.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with TexLive like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages={-},angle=30]{main}
\end{document}
```

It will rotate the entire pdf - every page!

I'm not the one who figured this out, however - [check this thread for the original solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233513/how-to-rotate-a-pdf) (and give that fellow a point!)

Answer (score 6):

Since you do not have to deal with annotations, you could try using any PDF library of your choice that allows you to decompose PDF dictionaries and decode the page content. Once you get the page content, you can insert a [transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) at the beginning of the page: [ cos θ sin θ −sin θ cos θ 0 0 ]

I would recommend taking a look at the [PDF Reference Document](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) from Adobe, specifically the section about the transformation matrix.

For example if you have the following page content object (40 0 obj):

```
10 0 obj % Page object
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 5 0 R
/Resources 20 0 R
/Contents 40 0 R
>>
endobj 
40 0 obj % Page content
BT
/F1 1 Tf
12 0 0 12 100 600 Tm
(Hello) Tj
ET
endobj
```

And you want to rotate the whole page by 45 degrees, assuming cos(45)=sin(45)=0.7,  your resulting page content will be:

```
40 0 obj
0.7 0.7 -0.7 0.7 0 0 cm
BT
/F1 1 Tf
12 0 0 12 100 600 Tm
(Hello) Tj
ET
endobj
```

After you finish adding the transformation matrix, you can re-compose your PDF file. The library you have chosen should then add compression filters and encoding filters as needed.

iText for example can decompose and recompose PDF files. See the method PdfReader.getPageContent for details.

Comment: You can actually open a pdf in notepad and see what you have shown us here.  I have a scanner that autoscans books, but they are always crooked, and dumb Acrobat won't do increments.  I wish I could use this simple method on my entire scanned pdf.

Comment: @BGM If you just need to process a single file, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12630604/501196
Once you get a "decompressed" pdf, you can modify each page content at will. The xref table will become corrupt, but you can probably repair it with the same tool.

Comment: That qpdf seems like a neat thing that I have to have in my repoitoire!  Thanks for the reference.  +1

Answer (score 6):

This is an example showing how to do that using Java and the iText library. With minimal changes that code should be usable with C# and iTextSharp, too, giving the sample @neo could not provide on short notice in his answer.

The sample takes the first page of`source.pdf`and inserts it into[`target.pdf`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHp9r.png)in all multiples of 30°, i.e. of 2*pi/12, but as that angle is explicitly given in the code, you can rotate by any angle.

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("target.pdf"));
document.open();

PdfReader origPdfReader = new PdfReader("source.pdf");
PdfImportedPage importedPage = writer.getImportedPage(origPdfReader, 1);

PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI * i / 6.0,
        importedPage.getWidth() / 2, importedPage.getHeight() / 2);
    canvas.addTemplate(importedPage, transform);
    document.newPage();
}
document.close();
```

Depending on your use case you may not only want to rotate (as you asked for) but also to scale it down to fit the page. In that case simply add`transform.scale(scaleX, scaleY)`before using the`transform`.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote some software which can do this:

cpdf -rotate-contents 45 in.pdf -o out.pdf

[Commercial](http://www.coherentpdf.com/), I'm afraid. See Chapter 3 of the [manual](http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf).

Comment: I've tried CPDF and indeed it does the job, and does it well. Also praises and thank you for the excellent e-mail support for your tool. 
I am currently going forward with the PDFLaTeX solution, but your answer qualifies as well.