# iText - rotate pages without rotation property

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I've got an existing PDF and I want to copy all pages to a new PDF-File. However, I would like to rotate pages by 90 degrees, but dont want to use the Page-Rotation-Property. I'm really new to itext and have not found a solution in Google.

Comment: If you don't want to use the page *Rotation* entry, you might want to use code akin to the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13601490/1729265).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it has really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it with this code. Thanks to mkl!

```
    PdfReader pdfIn = new PdfReader("source.pdf");
    Document document = new Document(getNormalizedPageSize(pdfIn), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("d:/target.pdf"));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfIn.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfIn, i);
        document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(page.getHeight(), page.getWidth()));
        document.newPage();
        float min = Math.min(page.getHeight(), page.getWidth());
        AffineTransform rotateInstance = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI / 2,
                min / 2.0, min / 2.0);
        double[] matrix = new double[6];
        rotateInstance.getMatrix(matrix);
        cb.addTemplate(page, (float) matrix[0], (float) matrix[1], (float) matrix[2],
                (float) matrix[3], (float) matrix[4], (float) matrix[5]);
    }
    document.close();
```