# Extract a Rectangle area of a PDF and paste it in a new PDF created with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

We have created a web system that shows and image and using JavaScript you can select a section which will be moved to a new PDF document.
To get this we have used the Java library iText.

Now we would like to do the same but instead of getting the portion of the image, we would like our users to be able to select a "Rectangle" in a PDF shown (we already got this to work) and move just the data in this area (covered by the Rectangle selected) to a new PDF.

Is this possible?, any idea where we can get some documentation about this or any examples??

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It is fairly easy to copy the whole page but only display a section... the whole page would be there, though.

Comment: @mkl: Agreed. The alternative, correctly hard clipping *any* PDF object at the boundaries, is so hard that even Acrobat itself shies away from it. Just adding Cropping to the page is a very reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to postscript, and use the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493559/ghostscript-postscript-pdf-cut-a-rectangle-from-a-ps-file-rotate-it-45-degree) for extracting a part of the page. Then convert back to pdf.

The conversions should be lossless (e.g. using pdf2ps/pdftops and ps2pdf).